# How can a Linux character device driver detect when a program using it exits abnormally?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, driver

I have a Linux character device driver that creates a `/dev/mything` entry, and then a C++/Qt program that opens the device and uses it. If that program exits correctly, with `exit()`, the device is closed and the driver properly resets itself. But if the program exits abnormally, via segfault or `SIGINT` or something, the device is not properly closed.

My current workaround is to reload the driver if it gets stuck in the "open" state.

This line in the driver tries to prevent multiple programs using the device simultaneously:

```
int mything_open( struct inode* inode, struct file* filp ) {
    ...
    if ( port->rings[bufcount].virt_addr ) return -EBUSY;
    ...
}
```

Then this cleans it up:

```
int mything_release( struct inode* inode, struct file* filp ) {
    ...
    port->rings[bufcount].virt_addr = NULL;
    ...
}
```

I think `exit()` is causing `mything_release` to be called but `SIGINT` is not. How can I make the driver more robust to this sort of situation?

EDIT:

Here are the operations I have implemented. Maybe I'm missing something?

```
static struct file_operations fatpipe_fops = {
    .owner =    THIS_MODULE,
    .open =     mything_open,
    .release =  mything_release,
    .read =     mything_read,
    .write =    mything_write,
    .ioctl =    mything_ioctl
};
```

Comment: When the proces exits or is terminated, the kernel will free the resources. Including the reference count on any open file descriptors.

Comment: If that's the case, why is it that after my program terminates with SIGINT/segfault, I get `Device or resource busy` when I try to reopen the program? I don't see that error if I exit it cleanly and reopen it.

Comment: I don't know your code. Maybe you have the wrong value for bufcount? Maybe you have not implemented one of the necessary functions ?

Comment: Looking at the `file_operations` struct, I'm thinking that might be the case. I have `release` implemented but not `flush`, and the comment here makes me think `flush` is important in my case: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-3

Comment: BTW: I am not a device driver writer. I suggest you take a look at how the other device drivers do it. I'd start with tty/serial, that is is oldest, and probably the most stable and correct one (especially wrt opening / closing : tty's used to have the habit of "hanging" under these kind of conditions. IIRC they even did a chmod on the device inode, but that could have been getty)

Comment: Should not there be a close() operation ?

Comment: @wildplasser `release` is the `close` function.

Comment: I wonder if you can retrieve some info about the opening process like the PID, compare it with the active PID you've stored, check if the old PID still exists. PID only may be not enough, maybe the process name too.

Comment: That is very likely, yes. Maybe it is not called ? Maybe it jumps out because of a stale lock? I'd look with lsof if there still is a reference to the inode, and maybe add some kprintf logging to see what happens when you kill the userspace program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem boiled down to this line in `mything_release`, put in to wait for some memory writes to complete:

```
if (wait_event_interruptible_timeout(port->inq, false, 10)) return -ERESTARTSYS;
```

With a normal program exit, this would spin for 10 jiffies and continue along. But with an abnormal exit from SIGINT or something, I think the interruptible timeout got interrupted and it returned `-ERESTARTSYS`, causing my if to return the same.

The thing that worked for me was to just get rid of the `if` and just wait:

```
wait_event_interruptible_timeout(port->inq, false, 10);
```

This patch from years ago made me believe that returning `ERESTARTSYS` from a close/_release function is not a good idea: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/patch-fix-wrong-error-code-interrupted-close-syscalls-help-181191441.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for this test; the problem is not abnormal program termination (which, from your driver's standpoint, is exactly like a normal `close` on the device) but instead a problem in the state keeping of your device. In other words, if you inserted `close(dev_fd)` or even `exit(0)` at the exact point where your program is crashing, you'd have the same problem.

You should figure out what part of your driver's behavior is causing it to remain in a busy state and fix that.

Comment: I took wildplasser's advice, above, and inserted some printk calls in `mything_release`. I found a line that reads `if ( wait_event_interruptible_timeout( port->inq, false, 10 ) ) return -ERESTARTSYS;`, and realized that with abnormal termination, it never gets past that line. Google makes me think ERESTARTSYS is not an ok thing to return from a close function.